# How should this C++ syntax be read?

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm probably being a complete idiot, but I've just seen this C++ syntax and I can't for the life of me work out what it's doing:

```
(*x)(&a, b, c);
```

A quick answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may find http://www.cdecl.org/ useful

Comment: @Adam12: That is not a declaration, and thus cdecl.org won't help much

Comment: Nice link, although I plugged what I'd written in, exactly as above, and it returned a `syntax error`.

Comment: You're correct it won't help for this particular code snippet but it is useful at times.

Comment: @EdKing: In C++ the types of any object are paramount. When posting code it is usually best that the code snippet contains the types of all objects used.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well there can be many more possibilities: it all depends on the type of all entities: `x`, `a`, `b`, `c`. In C++, you can overload even comma operator.

But I will only focus on `x`, and see how things turn out to be. The actual answer, however, will be too long if all combinations are taken into account.

```
(*x)(&a, b, c);
```

Here `x` could one of these:

- A function pointer
- A pointer to function object.
- An iterator which on dereferencing returns function pointer or function object.
- (one more at the bottom which is partially covered by the previous one!)

And then you're invoking it passing three arguments to it.

Here are few examples, assuming all other entities (`a`, `b` `c`) as `int`:

- An assumption

  ```
   int a,b,c; //FIXED as per the assumption
  ```
- Function pointer

  ```
   void f(int *,int, int);
   auto *x = f;
   (*x)(&a,b,c); //x is function pointer 
   x(&a,b,c);    //works fine, even without (*x)
  ```
- Function object

  ```
  struct X { void operator()(int*,int,int); };

  X y, *x = &y;
  (*x)(&a,b,c);  //x is pointer to function object
  ```
- Iterator

  ```
  std::list<std::function<void(int*,int,int)> l {X(), f};
  auto x = l.begin();  //x is an iterator
  (*x)(&a,b,c);  //(*x) is function object
  ++x;
  (*x)(&a,b,c);  //(*x) is function object (still!)

  //OR
  std::list<void(int*,int,int)> l {f};
  auto x = l.begin();  //x is an iterator
  (*x)(&a,b,c);  //(*x) is function pointer!
  ```

As @David said in comment that:

> However, there is a fourth possibility: x could be an instance of some class that overloads operator* to return a function pointer or function object.

which is true, but I believe this possibility is *partially* covered by iterator, or at least the iterator example gave you enough hint to figure it out yourself. :-)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please specify the reason?

Comment: Good point about the pointer to the function object.  And of course, if `x` has a class type, with an overloaded unary `*`, even more possibilities are present.  Not to mention if `b` has a user defined type, and there are overrides of the comma operator.  With clever use of overriding, the possibilities are endless.

Comment: @Nawaz I would also be curious of the reason. This answer is right.

Comment: I am not a downvoter. In fact, I'm an upvoter. However, there is a fourth possibility: `x` could be an instance of some class that overloads `operator*` to return a function pointer or function object.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Yes. that is yet another possibility, but that point is *partially* covered by *iterator*?

Comment: Nice post. Unless a better post takes place, me thinks this should be taken as the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that `x` is a function pointer. If this is the case, indeed, then it means:

1. dereference `x` to obtain an expression of function type;
2. call that function with arguments `addressof a`, `b` and `c`.

Also note that the `*` (dereference) and `()` operators around `x` are superfluous; you can write

```
x(&a, b, c);
```

as well if `x` is a function pointer.

Comment: Reason for the second downvote?

Comment: I guess the `()` and `*` that decorated `x` were that which confused me, especially if they're not needed, as you say. It is a function pointer. Thanks.

Comment: Reason for the third downvote? Oh, there was no third downvote (yet, but you never know :)). Jokes aside, the answer is correct although it assumes that `x` is a function pointer, it could very well be a pointer to a function object (in which case neither the parenthesis nor the `*` are superfluous). But I did not downvote.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Fair point! As I wrote, I *assumed* `x` was a function pointer. Also, there's that conditional saying **"if `x` is a function pointer",** so this should be fine (if I don't fail at logic :P )

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the definitions of the symbols, it's impossible to be 100% sure, but I suspect that it's a function call.  (Assuming `x` is a pointer to a function; if `x` has class type, it will depend on the overload of unary `*` in the class.)  So `(*x)` is dereferences the pointer, and logically is a function; given this, the rest should be obvious.  (Note that formally, a function decays into a pointer to the function in most contexts, and you call through a pointer to a function.  So if `x` is a pointer to a function `(*x)` and `x` are identical, as far as the compiler is concerned.  Not so human readers, however, and most will appreciate being told that the call is indirect.)

Answer (score 2):

The following is an example of using `operator()` which can produce an identical signature.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct sample {
    void operator()(int* a, int b, int c) {
        *a = b = c;
        return;
    }
};

int main() {
    sample* x;
    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;
    (*x)(&a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

x is probably a pointer to function, or pointer to pointer to function.

Answer (score 1):

It's calling a function through a function pointer.

Calling function pointed by pointer 'x' with the provided arguments.

This reference might be useful: [C++ Function pointer tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a call of a function pointed to by a *function pointer*. A more conventional syntax for it is as follows:

```
x(&a, b, c);
```

`x` points to a function that takes three arguments. The invocation expression dereferences the pointer, and passes the three arguments to the function the pointer points to.

An alternative could be that `x` is a pointer to an object that defines an override for a three-argument operator `()`. To know which one it is you need to supply more context.

Comment: A more conventional syntax for whom?  Say what you mean, and mean what you say, even if some arcane rules in the language don't require it.  If you have a pointer, and you want to use what it points to, dereference it.

Comment: @JamesKanze Back in the ANSI C standard days the language designers recognized that function pointers are special kind of pointers, and deserve a special syntax as such. They made it optional to dereference them explicitly. The explicit dereference has been left in there for backward compatibility, but as far as I remember it is ignored, at least in C.

Comment: Back in B (the predecessor of C), there where no types, and the `()` operator treated its argument as a function.  C followed this lead, but it was a fairly little used feature, at least in the C I've seen.  In C, pointers to functions were rare, and good programmers considered it important to use explicit syntax to draw attention to the fact that the call was indirect.  In C++, the fact that you don't explicitly need to dereference is there for reasons of C compatibility, but again, good C++ programmers don't use it (except incidentally, in templates).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `x` is either a pointer-to-pointer-to-function, or a pointer-to-functor.  `&a, b, c` is the argument list for the call.

Answer (score 0):

It's passing the arguments `&a, b, c` to a function pointed to by `*x`